# Ember-cli-simple-auth-devise, communicate with the server in an authorized way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, devise, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I have just created an App with Ember-cli 0.1.12, Rails 4.2, Ember-cli-simple-auth-devise and gem devise.

The Sign-in is succesfully completed, but when I try to get the data from the server it returns to me 'No authorization provided.'

It looks like the server is not receiving the token or the client is not sending it.

To create my App I used this guide:

https://adibsaad.com//blog/setting-up-ember-cli-with-a-rails-back-end-with-basic-authentication-authorization?utm_source=Ember+Weekly&utm_campaign=4ee2b59fd7-Ember_Weekly_Issue_96&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_e96229d21d-4ee2b59fd7-99322369

Thanks

Comment: Did you configure an authorizer as explained [here](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#authorizers)?

Comment: The server controllers have:
before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!
In config/environment.js file in clinet side:
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
crossOriginWhitelist: ['*'],
authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:devise'
};
ENV['simple-auth-devise'] = {
tokenAttributeName: 'authentication_token',
identificationAttributeName: 'email',
serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in',
authorizer: 'devise'
};
Now in Response Headers I can see:
Authorization: 
Token token="DDaPQTA-BoV3E8Rr_Kwn", email="test@test.com"
but it gives me another error, in preview:
Invalid authorization.